# C++ simultaneous assignment of values to variables

Tags: c++

I need to write a certain code segment in a c++ program that performs a task of the following type.

```
b:=a+b;
a:=a-b;
```

where := operator means that the value on the right hand side of all the expressions are computed first and then the variables on the left hand side of each expression is equated with the computed values on the right.

For example, in the above code, if a=5 and b=3, i would need the final value of a and b to be 8 and 2 respectively instead of 8 and -3 which i would get if i perform normal assignment.

Comment: This seems pretty easy if you assign `a` and `b` to temporaries and use the temporaries in the expressions that compute `a` and `b`. Are you trying to do it without using temporaries?

Comment: I was attempting to code the stochastic gradient descent algorithm in machine learning in which we have to simultaneously update the theta(parameter) values in every iteration.

Comment: @JamesAdkison But what if i had like a hundred variables? This is usually the case in gradient descent.

Comment: @Sibi, you can create hundred temporary variables. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: If you're dealing with a lot of values you should be using an appropriate container (e.g., `std::vector) and this logic could fit easily in a loop (or you could encapsulate it in any way you prefer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`std::tie()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) and [`std::make_tuple()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple):

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(a-b, a+b);
```

`tie` creates a tuple of references, and tuple assignment is equivalent to element-wise assignment. So this is effectively the same as:

```
// create the right-hand-side-tuple
auto __tmp1 = a-b;
auto __tmp2 = a+b;
// assign to the left-hand-side references
a = __tmp1;
b = __tmp2;
```

But since the assignment here is conceptually "atomic", you can write it all in one line - since all of the operations (the `a-b` and the `a+b`) are sequenced before the assignment itself.

Comment: Would i have to write this outside of the main function? Also, instead of a simple a+b and a-b, what if i had more complex equations?

Comment: @Sibi I don't understand what that question means - write what outside of where? Why would the complexity of the expression matter?

Comment: Nice.  This never even occurred to me.

Comment: Ok. Can someone explain what this actually does?

Comment: @Sibi It uses the expression `a-b` and `a+b` to create a `std::tuple` (i.e., a creative way to create the temporaries I was talking about) and then takes the values from the `tuple` and saves them back into `a` and `b`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use structures with names like `before` and `after` to hold your variables. Then, regardless of how many variables you have, you can use code as follows:

```
after.a = before.a + before.b;
after.b = before.a - before.b;
```

and then once your computations are done, you could move all the new values by the statement:

```
before = after;
```